# Mapping Object keys of two Object Arrays where order matters

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I have two arrays.

Array1 contains Objects like so (selectedHeaders in below code):

```
 [ { "text": "resource.id", "value": "resource.id" }, { "text": "resource.meta.versionId", "value": "resource.meta.versionId" }, { "text": "resource.resourceType", "value": "resource.resourceType" } ]
```

Array2 contains Objects like so (values in below code):

```
[ { "resource.resourceType": "One", "resource.id": "Two", "resource.meta.versionId": "Three", "resource.meta.lastUpdated": "Four" } ... and so on]
```

What I have so far is

```
values.forEach((value) => {
      Object.keys(value).forEach((val) => {
        selectedHeaders.forEach((element) => {
          if (val === element.value) {
            doThings();
          }
        });
      });
```

This works as long as values in Array1 are in the same order as they are in Array2 and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to change the code so that it maps values in Array2 to values in Array1. with arbitrary order and without external libraries (as vanilla as possible).

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

This should be converted to csv, in other words expected output should be:

```
resource.id;resource.meta.versionId;resource.resourceType
Two;Three;One
```

Comment: Please add a sample expected result.

Comment: Right, sorry. Added expected output.

Comment: Your `selectedHeaders` does not seem to make a lot of sense, to me; are the `text` and `value` attributes always equals to one another? If so, why you have two separate keys for the same data?

Comment: You are absolutely right, and no they are not. It was just just sample data and I couldn't think of a better way since the text-value didn't matter for my request. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following,

```
const ret = selectedHeaders.map((item) => {
      const index =  values.findIndex(bItem => Object.keys(bItem).includes(item.value));
      const value = values[index][item.value];
      return {[item.value]: value};
});

console.log(ret);
```